# behavior of bundler in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

when i run `bundle install` the first time this will create a gemfile.lock for me

after this my question is :

if i run `bundle install` for the second time what does bundler do ?

i think it look first at **gemfile.lock** and check each line, and then look in the **gemfile** and check gems that not exist in gemfile.lock then install them !!! i'm not sure , and i which if someone can explain that to me (step by step )

second question is :

for example i add a gem like this `gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.4.2'` , suppose after 1 month, version 1.4.3 is available. i think it will be installed automatically if i run bundle install again ?

can this new version "with tiny update" break things in my app ?

Answer (score 1):

The duty of `Gemfile.lock` is to lock the versions of the gems you use.
`bundle install` installs all gems in your `Gemfile` that are not in your bundle and records the version in `Gemfile.lock`.

`bundle install` only installs the versions of your gems, that are recorder in `Gemfile.lock`. It will **never update** any gem.

For updating gems, use `bundle update`. It looks for new versions of your gems, installs them and records the new versions in `Gemfile.lock`.

If you specify a version in your `Gemfile` like in your example

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.4.2'
```

`bundle upate` would only update `nokogiri` to revisions `< 1.5`
Any update (in fact any change) **might** break your application, but minor updates are **supposed** to be completely backward compatible (stable API, only new tests, all old test pass)

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/man/bundle-install.1.html),

> (...) the first time you run *bundle install* (and a **Gemfile.lock** does not exist), bundler will fetch all remote sources, resolve dependencies and install all needed gems.
>
> If a **Gemfile.lock** does exist, and you have not updated your **Gemfile**, bundler will fetch all remote sources, but use the dependencies specified in the **Gemfile.lock** instead of resolving dependencies.